# converting a list of list to dictionary containing a decimal

Tags: python, decimal

I am quite new to python so I tried to change a list of list to a dictionary by looping over it and defining a variblae that is a dictionary.

I have the result of a query as this:

```
 a = [
    [[1, 8, 2022], Decimal("666.6666666666666666666666667")],
    [[8, 8, 2022], Decimal("10000")],
]
```

I would like to convert it to dictionary like this:

```
data_dict = {
     'date': [1, 8, 2022],
      'kpi' : 666.67

}
```

I tried this code:

```
cob = None
for x in a:
    for b in x:
        v = {"date": b[0], "kpi": b[1]}
    cob = v
```

I got this error:

```
TypeError: 'decimal.Decimal' object is not subscriptable
```

how do I deal with this decimal
How do I achieve this goal?

thank you for your time in advance.

Comment: Looks like you have one too many for loops. Just `for b in a` should be enough.

Comment: Your error is that you are iterating through the list, and then through each element.
for b in x:
on first iteration b will be [1,8,2022] and second iteration b will be Decimal(666.666)
So your code is actually creating two dictionaries for each entry:
{"date":1, "kpi":8} and then trying do Decimal(666.66666)[0] which is where the error is coming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like the following will get it done. Within the list comprehension, only one level of iteration is taking place. Using `float` will take care of converting the `Decimal`.

```
[{'date': lst[0], 'kpi': float(lst[1])} for lst in a]
```

Yields:

```
[{'date': [1, 8, 2022], 'kpi': 666.6666666666666}, 
 {'date': [8, 8, 2022], 'kpi': 10000.0}]
```

Answer (score -1):

```py
cob = []
for b in a:
    v = {"date": b[0], "kpi": float(b[1])}
    cob.append(v)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can get the first index of every sublist in the larger list. Basically just use the zero index of each as the value.

```
d = {}
d["date"] = a[0][0]
d["kpi"] = a[1][0]
```

Comment: This does not appear to generate the result specified in the question.